# Extract words from string to create featureset nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am using NLTK and NLTK-Trainer to do some sentiment analysis. I have an accurate algorithm pickled. When I follow the [instruction](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/train_classifier.html#using-a-trained-classifier)s provided by NLTK-Trainer, everything works well.

Here what works (returns the desired output)

```
>>> words = ['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'sentence']
>>> feats = dict([(word, True) for word in words])
>>> classifier.classify(feats)
```

'feats' looks like this:

```
Out[52]: {'a': True, 'in': True, 'sentence': True, 'some': True, 'words': True}
```

**However**, I don't want to type in words separated by commas and apostrophes each time. I have a script that does some preprocessing on the text and returns a string that looks like this.

```
"[['words'], ['in'], ['a'], ['sentence']]"`
```

However, when I try to define the 'feats' with the string, I am left with something that looks like this

```
{' ': True,
 "'": True,
 ',': True,
 '[': True,
 ']': True,
 'a': True,
 'b': True,
 'c': True,
 'e': True,
 'h': True,
 'i': True,
 'l': True,
 'n': True,
 'o': True,
 'p': True,
 'r': True,
 's': True,
 'u': True}
```

Obviously the classifier function isn't very effective with this input. It appears like the 'feats' definition is extracting individual letters from the text string instead of whole words. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: By the way, `{word: True for word in words}` is more elegant than `dict([(word, True) for word in words])`

Comment: Why don't you use `nltk.word_tokenize()` to split the raw text in a list of tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand but I would suggest:

```
words = nltk.word_tokenize("some words in a sentence")
feats = {word: True for word in words}
classifier.classify(feats)
```

If you want to use your pre-processed text, try:

```
text = "[['words'], ['in'], ['a'], ['sentence']]"
words = text[3:len(text)-3].split("'], ['")
feats = {word: True for word in words}
classifier.classify(feats)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This got me on the right track, although the basic tokenizer still left the brackets as words. I was able to use the RegexpTokenizer to strip those out.